# turning list into dictionary python3.5

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am now trying to turn a list that looks like:

```
values = ['a 51', 'b 9', 'c 9', 'd 9', 'e 1']
```

into dictionary:

```
values = {'e': '1', 'c': '9', 'b': '9', 'a': '51', 'd': '9'}
```

For 117 of my lists it worked fine with

```
values = {str(i.split()[0]): i.split()[1] for i in values}
```

but unfortunately for three lists it didn't work and I get the ouput like this:

```
values = {'e': '1', 'c': '9', 'b': '9', 'a': '1', 'd': '9'}
```

making the largest value significantly smaller.

Separator I use in the list between key and value is space.

Any guesses on what I can do with that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need to see how these "failed lists" look like. BTW, your example code calls `split` more times than necessary ie an explicit for loop may preform better than the dict comprehension you used.

Comment: As you mentioned *"three lists it didn't work"*. Can you please share with us how that *three lists* look like. And what is your desired result for that?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the *generator* function with `dict` type as:

```
>>> values = ['a 51', 'b 9', 'c 9', 'd 9', 'e 1']

>>> dict(v.split() for v in values)
{'a': '51', 'c': '9', 'b': '9', 'e': '1', 'd': '9'}
```

---

In case you want to split the string with multiple spaces based on the first occurrence of the *space* (based on my understanding of your *three lists* issue), you may pass `maxsplit` argument to the `split` function as:

```
#               v  v two spaces in each string
>>> values = ['a 51 67', 'b 9 81', 'c 9 56', 'd 9 90', 'e 1 12']

#                 v   v  split string only on the first occurrence of the <space> 
>>> dict(v.split(' ', 1) for v in values)
{'a': '51 67', 'c': '9 56', 'b': '9 81', 'e': '1 12', 'd': '9 90'}
```

Comment: Besides being more compact and not doing all those unneccesary operations, how would this fix the (unknown) problem OP seems to have?

Answer (score 0):

If you have single space in each string then try below command

```
values = {str(i.split(' ')[0]): i.split(' ')[1] for i in values}
```

just used `split(' ')` instead of `split()` . if you need to include any other unknown separator or multiple spaces then let me know in comment.

Comment: may I know what's wrong in this solution and i got downvote?

Comment: Not my downvote, but maybe it's for still calling `split` twice and for the useless `str` conversion. Also, you should explain what's the benefit of using `split(' ')` w.r.t. the OPs problem. (This might actually solve the problem in case there are invisible whitespace chars in the string, but we don't know yet)

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a wild guess: Are you maybe trying the sort the result by values?

In this case, you should convert those numbers to `int` or else they will be sorted lexicographically (i.e. sorting `51` before `9`), hence making "the largest value significantly smaller" than expected for some of the lists.

```
>>> values = ['a 51', 'b 9', 'c 9', 'd 9', 'e 1']
>>> d1 = {k: v for k, v in map(str.split, values)}
>>> sorted(d1, key=d1.get, reverse=True)
['c', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'e']

>>> d2 = {k: int(v) for k, v in map(str.split, values)}    
>>> sorted(d2, key=d2.get, reverse=True)
['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e']
```